# How to run sh from sh file

Tags: shell, shell-script

I developed a Java application. I divided the application into 5 sub-applications, and created a service wrapper to each sub application using shell scripts:

```
subaap1/bin/app.sh
subaap2/bin/app.sh
...
```

Now I want to create a startup script `startup.sh` to execute all the wrapper scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
sh subaap1/bin/app.sh start
sh subaap2/bin/app.sh start
...
```

But when I run it, I get:

> Unexpected command: start

How can I fix this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that error is coming from your application.  What command do you type to just run subaap1?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to use sh in your script to run your sub applications.

Just use:

```
#!/bin/bash
subaap1/bin/app.sh start
subaap2/bin/app.sh start
...
```

Updated as per comments below:

your version should work, however you need to know what shell sh is calling. It may be that you have the wrong shell, or the permissions on your apps are incorrect for the shell you are trying to use.

Comment: Are you sure? `bash` will pass the arguments through to the script you're running (that's what my `sh` is symlinked to); I don't know about other shells

Comment: @Michael - will it pass them through if you use sh? You could be right - I just don't do it that way. I always surround mine in quotes if I want to do that. Or as here, just remove sh and bash is happy to assume the line is an application.

Comment: I have try to execute `subaap1/bin/app.sh start` from command line, and it works perfectly. Now I change the shell script without `sh` but I got `startup.sh: line 2: subaap1/bin/app.sh: Permission denied`. Any suggestion sir ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `sh /path/to/shell/script arg` and the arg made it through. It might depend which shell `sh` is actually linked to though

Comment: @Michael - good point! sh could go somewhere other than bash.